# Is it possible to include several content indexes in a latex project?

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing, report

I'm doing my final degree project in latex, using report. I need to include a general index for the complete project, and a specific index for each part of the project. Is there any possibility to do this in latex?.

Thank you

Comment: `imakeidx.sty` is one of the better choice...

Comment: The `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report`) provides for multiple indexes.